# Slow searching in php

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search

I'm new in php and mysql. Now i facing a problem is i need search data in a large database, but it take more than 3 minute to search a word, sometime the browser show timeout. I using technique FULLTEXT to do a searching, so any solution to decrease the searching time?

Comment: How large is the database? What does `EXPLAIN [sql statement]` say?

Comment: You're going to want to include *some* details, at least: what's the schema/indexes for the table(s) you're querying against, and what's the actual query you're running?

Comment: you can try `select requiredFields From tableName where field like '%inputText%'`

Answer (score 1):

create index for the table field which you will prefer subsequently, even it take some memory space query result should return best results within less time.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question directly but is a suggestion:

I had the same problem with full text search so I switched to SOLR:

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

It's a search server based on the Lucene library written in Java. It's used by some of the largest scale websites:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/PublicServers

So speed and scalability isn't an issue. You don't need to know Java to implement it however. It offers a REST interface that you can query and even gives the option to return the search results in PHP array format.

Here's the official tutorial:

https://builds.apache.org/job/Solr-trunk/javadoc/doc-files/tutorial.html

SOLR searches through indexed files so you need to get your database contents into xml or json files. You can use the Data Import Handler extension for that:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler

To query the REST interface you can simply use `get_file_contents()` php function or CURL. Or the PHP sdk for SOLR:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolPHP

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how big your database is. Adding an index for the field you are searching is the first thing to do.

I have been into the same problem and adding an index for the field worked great.